# VS Code + JavaScript + eslint show error when calling an object with invalid key

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, linter

I'm looking for a way for vs code with the combination of eslint to give me an error or a warning when I call an invalid key on an object. In this specific case I've created a global constant object with five keys and when I call something made up like Foo on this object I want there to be an error saying Foo hasn't been defined.

example:

```
const COLORS = { BLUE: 1, RED: 2, GREEN: 3 }
somefunction(COLORS.foo)  // show warning or error
```

I Have done a dozen or so searches for answers or extensions looking at ES Lint website , SonarCube Extension and none of these seem to solve this simple problem.  Yes I know TS can handle this but our project is in JS.

Comment: `const` means the variable can't be reassigned, it doesn't mean the object is immutable. Nothing prevents you from doing `COLORS.foo = 4;`

Comment: Bite the bullet and switch to Typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwgeQDIIEoGUYF4YG8YBCSAqgKIBcMAjADQyqkAilATHQOIOkBylAzDAC+AKEQoMAOgBmIEEA

Comment: Yes I understand how const works and I know all about typescript as I mentioned in the post. This isn't a assignment this is calling the constant

Comment: There’s probably an existing static analyzer *somewhere* that does this (it probably wouldn’t be too hard to write your own ESLint plugin either), but for what it’s worth, I would usually do `const COLOR_BLUE = 1;` etc. instead.

Comment: Why would a tool, whatever it is, warn about something that is not an error? Also, the test suite would totally detect the issue so there is no need to find a way to lie to the language Syntax checkers since you covered the code with a test.

Comment: @EricMORAND Linters are supposed to look for likely problems and poor coding style, not just actual errors.

Comment: Likely problems don't exist. Either there is a problem and the test suite detects it - hence removing it - or there is no problem - the tests pass. Linting doesn't detect problems: testing does. Here, there is no need to prevent the developer to assign or access another property of the constant: the test would fail if one does.

Comment: @EricMORAND: Testing alone isn’t an adequate replacement for proving properties of code using type systems, static analysis, etc. – that’s why we have those things. It’s one tool in the kit.

Comment: I agree. What I mean is that asking for a tool that would display an error for something that is perfectly legit in JavaScript - creating and assigning to an object property - is not something that should be considered as legit and encouraged

Comment: @EricMORAND Are you saying that based on the code above a linter couldn't figure out that the variable foo is not available on the const COLORS if no where in the code .foo is ever used?

Comment: @JesseBoyd I'm saying that if the code above passes the tests that cover it, then it is correct and no linting rule can do anything about it. It the above code is not correct then its tests would fail and force the developer to fix it by not accessing the foo property. You agree that if the test expect that either 1, 2 or 3 is returned whenever a property of COLORS is accessed, then it would fail when undefined is returned, right?

Comment: Agree with @Phil - This is exactly the scenario TypeScript was initially created for.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere, a test exists that looks like this:

```js
assert(whateverFunctionThatAccessOneOfCOLORSProperty() === aValueComputedFrom1or2or3);
```

This test fails whenever someone is making use of a value that is not 1, 2 or 3, so there is no need for linting.

What you are trying to achieve is vain because it would only prevent developers from accessing an undefined property of COLORS, but would not prevent them from  using a non valid value *without* accessing COLORS:

```js
import {COLORS} from "./colors";

function computeSomethingFromCOLORS() {
    // don't access COLORS at all
    return 4;
}
```

Linting would not trigger - because as you can see nobody is accessing COLORS - but the test suite would definitely fail.

Linting is by no mean a replacement for proper testing.

EDIT: This goes true with TypeScript. Typing is not a replacement for testing. It is a convenient way to not having to wait until the compilation is done and the test suite run to detect syntactic issues. No typed language can ever replace a test suite.

Comment: “Somewhere, a test exists that looks like this” – not necessarily; “This test fails whenever someone is making use of a value that is not 1, 2 or 3” – not necessarily. The point about failing to use a `COLORS` value at all is good, but it doesn’t mean this hypothetical linting plugin wouldn’t be useful.